# Node with Opa app crashes when trying to connect to unavailable CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, opa

I am working on Opa app using CouchDB as a database backend. When fetching a document with API function `CouchDd.Document.get` ([API doc](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.apis.couchdb/CouchDb/Document/get)) and the DB server is down, my app crashed:

```
/opt/mlstate/lib/opa/stdlib/server.opp/serverNodeJsPackage.js:169
,(global.hasOwnProperty("toString") && global.toString || undefined)(e));}req.
                                                                    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ClientRequest.on_error (/opt/mlstate/lib/opa/stdlib/server.opp/serverNodeJsPackage.js:169:489)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1320:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

and returns to shell prompt. I am running the app with `./myapp --nodb`, because I do not use the build-in support for the MongoDB.

The `CouchDb.Document.get` function returns either `{success: {FormatedJson: ...}}` or `{failure}`. I expected that parsing the result for the `{failure}` is enough to catch all the network connection problems. What else should I do?

I am using Opa framework version 1.0.5 on OSX (11.4.0 Darwin) from the standard package on the Opa website, Node.js v0.8.3 and CouchDB 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 1.0.5, but it's been fixed already. You can get the sources for the fixed version [here](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/tree/v3179), but an official package hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I rather will not build it from sources on my main working box and will wait for the official package. I also have some Linux box for experiments (I will deploy on Linux) where I was already building Opa, so I may have a try just to check if it is working. The last time I was trying to build on Linux, Gentoo port was broken, but perhaps it is already corrected.. I hope :)

Comment: You can download the nightly here : http://opalang.org/get.xmlt#opalang_package_view=nightly